# Spring Controller Ajax request STATUS 400

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, spring, post

Would like to post two integers to a controller using Java Spring, here is my attempt thus far:

I am trying to use jQuery's $.post as follows:

```
var active = $(this).is(':checked');
var sprint_id = active_sprint_id;
$.post("sprints/toggleactive",
{
   id: sprint_id,
   active: active
},
function(data, status){

});
```

Here is my controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/sprints/toggleactive", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody String setActive(@RequestParam("id") int id, @RequestParam("active") int setActive) {

}
```

I am getting a 400 response, and I've noticed if I remove one of the parameters it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a silly mistake on my end.

```
// active is a boolean
var active = $(this).is(':checked');
```

So the @RequestMapping should be of type boolean.

I was able to eventually realize this by visiting the console in my browser and seeing the Java stack trace.